# Alignment and chemical formula

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, chemistry

I would like to write this with Latex as an example:

```
Anode:                    H2 -> 2H+ + 2e-

Cathode:   0.5O2 + 2e- + 2H+ -> H2O
```

It does not work.
Either Anode and Cathode are not aligned well or the reaction equation is broken.
I tried a lot and did not find a good solution.
This is where I am, the both cases:

```
\begin{flalign}
\text{Anode:}~ \ce{3O2- &-> 1.5O2 + 6e-} \\
\text{Cathode:}~ \ce{N2 +  3H2O + 6e- &-> 2NH3 + 3O2-}
\end{flalign}`


\begin{flalign}
  &\text{Anode:}~ \centering \ce{3O2- &-> 1.5O2 + 6e-} \\
  &\text{Cathode:}~ \centering \ce{N2 +  3H2O + 6e- &-> 2NH3 + 3O2-}
\end{flalign}
```

Can somebody please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, ensure you provide a fully compilable example of code in the future, so we don't have to guess what packages you're using.

For `flalign` you need more alignment points, but I suggest just `alignat` so the distance is not as big. I see no reason for flushing “Anode” and “Cathode” with the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{flalign}
&\text{Anode:}   & \ce{3O2-             &-> 1.5O2 + 6e-} & \\
&\text{Cathode:} & \ce{N2 +  3H2O + 6e- &-> 2NH3 + 3O2-} &
\end{flalign}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{alignat}{2}
&\text{Anode:}   &\qquad \ce{3O2-             &-> 1.5O2 + 6e-} \\
&\text{Cathode:} &\qquad \ce{N2 +  3H2O + 6e- &-> 2NH3 + 3O2-}
\end{alignat}
\lipsum[2][1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]